# What are the other # Areas of the Holy Empire of Britannia?

Tags: code-geass

At the start of Code Geass Japan has just been conquered by Britannia and renamed Area 11. After Prince Clovis's death we are introduced to Princess Cornelia, learning that her Knights had just established another Area for the Empire (I do not remember the number) before leaving to take Clovis's place in Area 11.

I am wondering what each of the Areas are (ie. Area 11 is Japan), if they were conquered in the order they are numbered and if they were all also conquered while Charles Zi Britannia was Emperor.

Comment: NOTE: the last bit about Charles I ask because Bartley says later on that he believes the reason for most of the Wars were to secure Geass related Ruins like the ones found at Kamine Island and am curious which Areas Charles have conquered which possibly have Geass Ruins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An Area is a nation or group of nations that has been conquered by
>   Britannia and made into a colony. Each Area is designated with a
>   number, and its people are referred to by that number.

...

> Areas are numbered in order of conquest, though only a handful are mentioned by
>   name

1. United States - Disputed (considering the timeline, the United
   States doesn't exist in this world) In addition, Britannians make
   several mentions to the "Homeland" suggesting that there's a part of
   their empire that isn't an Area. Since the original colonies that
   Britannian nobles fled to after losing Great Britain were in North
   America, it would make sense that at least part of the United States
   as well as possibly part of Canada, would be the "Homeland".
2. Canada and Queen Elizabeth Islands
3. Mexico
4. Greenland
5. Iceland
6. South America
7. Hawaii and Midway Atoll
8. Falkland Islands
9. New Zealand
10. Indochina - Disputed (Indochina is shown as a territory of the
     Chinese Federation)
11. Japan
12. Philippines
13. Cambodia - Disputed (While Britannia seems to have connections with
     Cambodia, it was never called an Area) In addition, Cambodia is
     considered a part of Indochina.
14. Papua New Guinea
15. Southern Pacific Islands
16. Korean Peninsula - Disputed (Shown as a territory of the Chinese
     Federation)
17. Indonesia - Disputed (shown as a territory of the Chinese
     Federation, especially taking part of the uprising)
18. Middle Eastern Federation
19. Unknown
20. Unknown
21. Unknown
22. Unknown
23. Unknown
24. Spain

[Source](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Holy_Britannian_Empire)

Comment: Do you know which Area was the first to be conquered while Charles was on the throne given that they are numbered in order by conquest?

Comment: @Memor-X I watched the anime again and their is no mention about your question. This is only my speculation but Charles was childhood friends with VV and their priority mission was to find the thought elevators around the world http://prntscr.com/8af99s. So first they found one in New York while they were young. In 1998 they overtook the Emperor of Britannia using Geass and started searching the elevators by conquering Canada.